# Can we use a .NET Assembly compiled on windows platform with winsock depdenency on linux using mono

Tags: .net, linux, mono

The title summarizes the question.

I have a Shaft Encoder (a hardware that generates pulses) with C# API That interfaces with it.  API works great on Windows, it has a .NET Assembly DLL that I have to hook up my program to.

However, I would like to use this API on Linux, I have the following two questions.

1. Can I write a Wrapper around this DLL using Mono-Framework and use it under Linux ?
2. What if the API uses Windows Sockets, would that be an issue for Linux ?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA This tool is no long actively maintained, but it should tell you whether you will encounter any significant issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.

HTH. Have a nice day.